# Want to get CF7 HTML table <td> input fields value on my email

Tags: contact-form-7

Want to get CF7 HTML table  input fields value on my email but I can't understand how can I retrieve table values in my email.

***here is my code***

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="column-full" align="center">
        <h1>YOUR PROFILE</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="column-full"
        <table border="1" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>For Registration Purpose</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="30"/></td>
                <td>Registration #</td>
                <td><input type="text" size="30"/></td>       
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Posted by </td>
                <td><input type="text" size="30"/></td>
                <td>CV ID # </td>
                <td><input type="text" size="30"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-row">
    <div class="column-half">
        <h4>Name : </h4> [text* your-name]
    </div>
    <div class="column-half">
        <h4>Father's Name : </h4> [text* father-name]
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to build a grid layout form in cf7.  html tables are notoriously unresponsive, so not a good practice to use them.
I would recommend you use the [CF7 Smart Grid-layout extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) plugin to build your grid form instead.  It builds grid forms which are responsive by default.
Next, if you want to insert submitted values into the notification mails, you need to use cf7 tags rather than your own `<input>` fields.  The cf7 plugin does not recognise custom html fields and that is the reason you don't see them as being available when setting up your mail.

So instead of `<input type="text" name="your-text"/>` you would use `[text your-name]` and let the cf7 plugin handle the creation of the html field.